# how do i slightly change the postion of an object in after effects that is connected to a null object?

Tags: after-effects, null-object-pattern

I am trying to only slightly change the poison of an object that is whipped to a null

`thisComp.add(125,250).layer("Null 1").transform.position`

and it wouldn't work.

right now a null is making sure that the object is moving forward but it is moving my object too much forward and making my object too big.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not moving the null object so far, therefore stopping it from making your object too big.

Or, if that's not viable, change the anchor point position.